# how to change for loop code to pythonic way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have one code its very slow , please is there anyway to change it to fast?

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,4,5,67,8,8,89,9,98,7,87,87,87,89,89,9,8,9,9,909,9,8,9,8,9,89,8,8,9,89]})
a=0.0119  
x1=df['value']
Y=x1.iloc[0:10]
Y_mean=np.mean(Y)
previous=Y_mean

for i in range(len(x1)):
    y=a*x1.values[i]+previous
    previous=(1-a)*y
    y=pd.DataFrame([y])
    dff2=dff2.append(y)
```

Comment: Please show the whole code

Comment: @WeNYoBen its full code buddy :)

Comment: If it were the full code, I could copy and run it. What do you expect will happen if I try to run `x1=df['value']` as my first line? Please see the SO help page on creating a **[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.

Comment: Then where is a

Comment: @WeNYoBen   I changed question please check now

Comment: looks like you want `df['value'].ewm(a).mean()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you calculated is called `ewm mean` in pandas, so you can just use the `ewm().mean()` method. 
Here is the code to get the same result as your code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,4,5,67,8,8,89,9,98,7,87,87,87,89,89,9,8,9,9,909,9,8,9,8,9,89,8,8,9,89]})
a=0.0119  
Y=x1.iloc[0:10]
Y_mean=np.mean(Y)
s = df["value"]
pd.concat([pd.Series([Y_mean/(1-a)]), s]).ewm(alpha=a, adjust=False).mean().iloc[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for value in x1['values']:
    y, previous = pd.Dataframe([a * value + previous]), (1-a)*y
    dff2=dff2.append(y)
```

Comment: @L.F., future readers are secondary users, not the primary one(s).  The OP question is the context, both now and in the future.  Regarding the explanation, I don't see much difference between this answer and the accepted one.